# "application has stopped working" while applying Hotfix rollup #2

Tags: 2011

I'm trying to install de HR2 for Tridion 2011 SP1,

HR1 already installed:

- Content Manager Explorer - Revisión  6.1.0.55920
- Content Manager - Revisión   6.1.0.997
- Actualizar versión - Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1

I followed the steps to apply the hotfix , first applying the script in order to update the DB.

The problem appears when I try to run the patch for the content manager. It always fails with an windows error:

> application has stopped working.

Some idea?

Comment: Please could you look through the installer logs (C:\ProgramData\SDL\Chainer\Logs) to see if anything is logged?

Comment: No files in the Logs folder. I repaired .NEt Framework 4 but still the same error:                                        `Nombre del evento de problema: CLR20r3
  Firma del problema 01: sdltridion2011sp1hr2.exe
  Firma del problema 02: 6.1.0.231
  Firma del problema 03: 5044b448
  Firma del problema 04: System.Configuration
  Firma del problema 05: 4.0.0.0
  Firma del problema 06: 5192a871
  Firma del problema 07: 569
  Firma del problema 08: 6b
  Firma del problema 09: IOIBMURHYNRXKW0ZXKYRVFN0BOYYUFOW
  Versión del sistema operativo:6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Id. de configuración regional:3082`

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR#2 installer as the user who originally installed SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 / SP1 HR#1?  You could try renaming the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` configuration file to something else, for example `Tridion.ContentManager.config.BCKP` - once the installer is run, you can delete the one created by the upgrade, and then rename `Tridion.ContentManager.config.BCKP` to `Tridion.ContentManager.config`

Comment: I renamed the config file, but the error is still appearing.

Comment: At last I have installed the HR2 using the same user that installed the HR1 (the user of a colleague). That works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to contact Tridion Customer Support...

[Customer Support](http://www.sdl.com/support/web-content-management-products/)